# Linear transformations question with polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Find the matrix $A$ that represents the linear transformation $T$ with respect to the bases $B$ and $B'$:

(b) $T : P_3 \to P_3$ given by $$T(a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+a_3 x^3)=(a_0+a_2)-(a_1+2a_3)x^2$$ where $B,B'=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$.

I think I'm supposed to find $T(1)$, $T(x)$, $T(x^2)$ and $T(x^3)$ but I find the the way the transformation is given confusing and I'm not really sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is OK. You have $T(1)=1$, $T(x)=-x^2$, $T(x^2)=1$, $T(x^3)=-2x^2$, so the matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&-2\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
As to evaluating the values of $T$ on the basis. You have, for instance, $$T(1)=T(1+0x+0x^2+0x^3)=(1+0)-(0+2\cdot 0)x^2=1,$$
$$T(x^3)=T(0+0x+0x^2+1x^3)=(0+0)-(0+2\cdot 1)x^2=-2x^2.$$ Hope this helps.

Comment: How did you come up with $T(1), T(x), T(x^2), T(x^3)$? Wouldn't they involve any of the coefficients like $a_0$?

Comment: @user326441 Added.

Comment: I was about to say I will accept it in a minute when it lets me to :)